# click_ok on xpath Element Locator: i can check it but not click on it

Tags: selenium, xpath

I can check xpath Element Locator, but when I try click_ok on the same xpath Element Locator. I receive this error.

### Error

```
# Error requesting http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/:
# ERROR: Invalid xpath [2]:(//table[@onclick='DeviceListManager.element_onclick(this);'])[7].0.2
not ok 14 - click, xpath=(//table[@onclick='DeviceListManager.element_onclick(this);'])[7].0.2
#   Failed test 'click, xpath=(//table[@onclick='DeviceListManager.element_onclick(this);'])[7].0.2'
#   at watchtest.pl line 55.`
```

### Check Element Locator work correct

`$sel->table_is("xpath=(//table[\@onclick='DeviceListManager.element_onclick(this);'])[7].0.2", "Overflows");`

### click on the same Locator doesn't work.

```
$sel->click_ok("xpath=(//table[\@onclick='DeviceListManager.element_onclick(this);'])[7].0.2");
```

use: perl_5.8.9, selenium IDE 2.8.0

### Using Xpath Checker I found

```
id('MainContentContainer')/x:table/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[1]/x:div/x:div/x:div[1]/x:div/x:div/x:table[9]/x:tbody/x:tr/x:td[3]
```

### Element in code

```
<table class="item-header inner-closed" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" onmousedown="DeviceListManager.draggableItem_OnMouseDown(event, this);" ondblclick="DeviceListManager.element_ondblclick(this);" onclick="DeviceListManager.element_onclick(this);" itemtype="xsd:int" itempath="ITDiag" url="undefined" itemname="itdiag/Connections.Overflows" devname="undefined">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<td class="img variable-img">
<td class="text">Overflows</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any Idea? 
Thanks Pavel

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading the frame. See what xpath checker returnes. It is showing id('MainContentContainer'). You have to load this frame first. Use below code

```
driver.switchTo().frame(ID_or_NAME);
```

now perform the click action.